# C++ builder change main menu background color

Tags: c++, menu, background-color, c++builder

Here is script which demonstrates how to change background color on main menu items, while the rest part of the menu still remains in gray color

```
 void __fastcall TForm1::AdvancedDrawNewItemMain(TObject *Sender, TCanvas *ACanvas,    const TRect &ARect,
      TOwnerDrawState State)
{

    TMenuItem *MenuItem = ((TMenuItem*)Sender);
    TRect  TempRctN = ARect;
    TempRectN.top=TempRctN.top+2;
    ACanvas->Brush->Color =clRed;
    ACanvas->FillRect(ARect);


    DrawTextW(ACanvas->Handle,MenuItem->Caption.w_str(),MenuItem->Caption.Length(),&TempRctN, DT_CENTER);


  if((State.Contains(odSelected) || State.Contains(odHotLight) ) && !State.Contains(odDisabled) )
  {
   ACanvas->Brush->Color =static_cast<TColor>RGB(49,106,197);
   ACanvas->FillRect(ARect);
   ACanvas->Font->Color=clWhite;
   DrawTextW(ACanvas->Handle,MenuItem->Caption.w_str(),MenuItem->Caption.Length(),&TempRctN, DT_CENTER);
  }

}
```

does anybody know how to change whole mainmenu background color?

Answer (score 0):

The OS does not support what you are asking for.  A standard `TMainMenu` can only owner-draw the individual items, not the entire menu as a whole.  If you want to customize the entire menu, you will have to use a different component, such as finding a third-party custom menu implementation that supports what you need.

Comment: Remy, thank you very much for your answer. Can you indicate which component shuold I use to solve the problem?